# How to use Proc.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I was curious about this line:

```
set :views, Proc.new
```

What it do, and why is `Proc.new` used?

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "../views/") }
    enable :sessions unless test?
    set :session_secret, "secret"
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you asking what a `Proc` is? https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Proc.html

Comment: @RockwellRice that helps.

Comment: Did you research this? If not, why? If so, why didn't it help? We need to see evidence of your effort toward understanding this. Currently, it looks like you didn't do anything and want us to research and explain it for you, which is definitely not the SO way. These help explain: "[ask]" and the linked pages,
"[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and
"[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proc is not a static thing, it takes a settings value `root` and evaluates a path to views.
Here is a piece of documentation of Sinatra:

> When the setting value is a `Proc`, evaluation is performed every time the setting is read so that other settings may be used to calculate the value

Once you set `root` value you don't need to set the full path for views.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I think I'm still having a hard time grasping exactly what Proc does.